# How can I optimize a symbol-specialist wizard?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells, optimization

In an upcoming campaign that starts at level 12 and that has PCs start with typical wealth for a PC of that level I'd like to play a wizard whose specialty is the various *symbol* spells. What classes and prestige classes, feats, traits, and magic items should my PC have to be a *symbol*-tossing wizard that's effective *both* economically (those symbol spells are pricey) *and* in combat?

#### Details

- The campaign setting is the underdark of the Forgotten Realms.
- 20 point-buy for ability scores.
- Other PCs include a rogue specializing in the Intimidate skill, a lore warden fighter specializing in dirty tricks, a juju oracle specializing in necromancy, and an inquisitor specializing in archery. My PCs alignment isn't important for getting along with this group—they're all over the alignment map.
- Material from *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5e* is acceptable. Third-party *Pathfinder* material is also acceptable.

Comment: [Related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67518/8610)

Comment: [Also related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91954/can-glyph-of-warding-be-cast-on-a-weapon-or-ammunition-so-that-an-attack-activat)

Comment: I made a pretty substantial edit to this in an effort to stave off closure. I hope that's okay. I think the breadth of the material that the question introduced might've been overly intimidating so I tried to scale it back a bit. If it's no longer asking what you want it to ask or I've omitted details that you think are important, please edit the question further or rollback.

Comment: We can't answer optimisation questions unless you tell us what to optimise *for.* As such, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @GMJoe I… I thought that was covered by *What… should my PC have to be a symbol-tossing wizard that's effective both economically (those symbol spells are pricey) and in combat?* So optimizing to use *symbol* spells in combat on the cheap? Honestly, was it clearer before the edit? I tried to make this even clearer not muddy it up!

Comment: How do you feel about being an Aboleth?  How does your group do LA buyoff?

Comment: @ H.I.C.C. ... I definitely appreciate your efforts to make the question more appealing to the RPGSE folks ... but I'm not sure why my original details threatened "closure" (and I'm not sure what that means either, lol). That all said, the responses I'm getting (which I also appreciate) are addressing my OP more peripherally than head-on. I'll take the blame for that, though.

Comment: (Lots of questions—and especially optimization questions—are put on hold because not enough information is provided, but sometimes questions are put on hold because the amount of information is overwhelming. In this question's case, I think some of the introductory text prevented folks from seeing the parts they needed to see to know the question was answerable… so I excised those nonessential parts to make this question hurry up and get to the point.)

Answer (score 2):

### Geometer

The only thing that immediately comes to mind is the Geometer prestige from Complete Arcane. You probably also want to pick up the Etch Schema feat as well from Eberron for the unique cost savings rules associated with it in addition to checking out the [cost reduction handbook](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1000).

The [handbook](http://www.minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=1000) is so extensive, that it exceeds the scope of this answer. (Please note that the link is to an old version of the handbook, and does not contain the final edits or additions.)

> The advantage to the Etch Schema feat is that it is produces a minor schema: basically a once-per-day 1st through 6th level scroll that doesn't get destroyed after use and has no arcane spell failure chance. I'm sure that the advantages of an effectively infinitely reusable scroll, even if it is only once per day, for item creation purposes or, say, a symbol user should be self-evident. Especially if you make more than one.

Watch out of AoOs or distractions during activation, though.

Comment: Could you detail the unique cost savings associated with creating a minor schema?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Added your request.

Comment: As it's not enough for an answer on its own and as you're already linking there, it might be worth mentioning the build [**master of glyphs**](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=10643.0), which, while *not* specializing in the *symbol* spells, nonetheless specializes in those *other* popular magical writings, *glyphs of warding.* (If you opt not to mention it, I guess that's okay since I've mentioned it here. `:-)`)